# Why is Chrome ignoring my executeScript command in my extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to figure out exactly how Content Scripts work.

I'm writing an extension with a context menu that, once the option is clicked, the next click will result in an alert dialog with information about the page the element is on and the id and name of the element clicked.

I think my problem is including the name of the content script file somewhere on my manifest, since I am using `executeScript` to use it instead of having it injected on every single web page but I cannot figure out where to put it.

Please let me know if I can provide more helpful information.

Here are copies of my manifest, the main script I use and the script that I am trying to insert.

Manifest.json

```
    {
      "name": "Omnixx Page Object Builder",
      "description": "Finds information about an element clicked, started with a context menu",
      "version": "0.3",
      "permissions": ["tabs", "contextMenus", "activeTab"],
      "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["menuBuilder.js"]
      },
      "manifest_version": 2
    }
```

menuBuilder.js

```
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
  if (info.menuItemId == "start") {
    console.log("Started trying to find elements");
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"elementTracker.js"});
    console.log("Started listening...");
  } 
};

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Find element information", "id": "start", "contexts":["all", "page", "frame", "selection", "link", "editable", "image","video", "audio"], });
});
```

elementTracker.js

```
function click(event) {
    // Begin building the message
            var msgToWrite = "";

            var curscreen = window.HIDEFRAME.document.getElementsByName("curscreen")[1].value;
            msgToWrite += "curscreen: '" + curscreen + "'\n";

            var url = content.document.URL;
            msgToWrite += "URL: " + url + "\n";

            // A try-catch block is necessary for finding the frame; otherwise the code
            // will fail for pages without frames
            try {
                var frame = event.originalTarget.ownerDocument.defaultView.frameElement;
                var frameName = frame.getAttribute("name");

                if (frameName != null) {
                msgToWrite += "Frame: '" + frameName + "'\n";
                } else {
                    msgToWrite += "No frame found\n";
                }
            } catch (e) {
                msgToWrite += "No frame found\n";
            }

            // Get the element's ID
            var elemID = event.target.getAttribute("id");

            if (elemID != null) {
                msgToWrite += "ID: '" + elemID + "'\n";
            } else {
                msgToWrite += "No ID found\n";
            }

            // Get the element's name
            var elemName = event.target.getAttribute("name");

            if (elemName != null) {
                msgToWrite += "Name: '" + elemName + "'";
            } else {
                msgToWrite += "No name found";
            }

            // Create a pop-up message
            alert(msgToWrite);
}

document.addEventListener('click', click);
```

Comment: I've edited your question, please avoid "wall of text", it's the sure way to not get an answer here in Stack Overflow. Welcome, and good luck. You should probably clarify your question further as I've developed chrome extensions before and I'm still not sure what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening is that you're trying to call another event listener at the end of your `elementTracker.js` file. You don't need that because you're initializing the script from the context menu call.

Change the last line in that script to `click(event)`. The script will be injected to the page from the context menu.

Comment: Just tried that, I didn't notice any change and my extension still isn't arriving in that script from menubuilder.js

Comment: You can check the console on the page you're trying to inject it into. The script showed up for me when I clicked on the browser action. It won't show up in the extension console.

Comment: I just tested it again on my machine and I can see the script being injected into the webpage from the context menu. It looks like there are some bugs in your `elementTracker.js` that need some work. [Here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yo7x3lyqWFI) showing my testing.